# JPA LOWER() function not working with create query

Tags: java, jpa

I had a typed query like:-

```
TypedQuery<peakdto> query= entityManager.createQuery("peak",peakdto);
```

here

```
peak= "select LOWER(d.component) from peakdto d where d.peak= 'sar'";
```

Here the problem is `LOWER()` function is not working.
getting error like unexpected token LOWER.

Comment: How can `LOWER(d.component)` give a `peakdto` object as a result?

Comment: dont think about that, here the thing is lower() is not working , this is the only issue

Comment: But your code is broken if it's like that. The `TypedQuery` claims that the result is a `peakdto`, yet you use `LOWER(d.component)` which only makes sense if the result is a `String`.

Comment: If you get an exception then you quote the exception + stack trace. What is "d.component" ? without the class and exception impossible to comment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, hadn't the time to read the docs completly.
But the String Functions like "LOWER" are only usable in the WHERE part of the query.
In the Select part it makes no sense, because the conversion to lower case is easyly done in the Result set object.

For example when your JPA Query returns Pojo MyEntity then you can implement it this way:

```
public class MyEntity {
  private String value;

  public String getValue(){}
  public void setValue(String value) {}
  public String getValueLowerCase() {
    return value.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Comment: FWIW JPA spec allows LOWER in SELECT clause (but as you say it is of little reasonable use).

Comment: OK then forget my answer ;) Possible that the JPA impl. used is not supporting it as expected.